# Statements inside double curly braces in XML document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am hoping someone can tell me what the following {{object|LANDevice}} is supposed to be used for? It looks like an xPath statement for selecting the LANDevice node but why the double curly braces? and what would it return, the node name?

```
<parameter name="LANDeviceNumberOfEntries" access="readOnly">
<description>Number of instances of {{object|LANDevice}}.</description>
   <syntax>
       <unsignedInt/>
   </syntax>
</parameter>
```

The full XML document is [here](http://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/tr-069-1-0-0.xml). There seems to be a lot of these double curly brace statements but I'm not sure how they are intended to be used.

**EDIT:** It turns out this is MediaWiki markup. The double curly braces are used to denote a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like notation for some documentation-generation tool.

Comment: I am hoping it is a standard of some kind. I thought it might have something to do with XSLT but I can't find any references to it.

Comment: Not part of the XML standard.  This is intended to be processed by some third-party tool.

Comment: Come to think of it, this looks suspiciously like MediaWiki double-brace markup.

Comment: MediaWiki is hardly the only popular tool to use double braces for notation.

Comment: @Jim Garrision Your right, turns out it is MediaWiki-inspired markup.

Answer (score 3):

It's not XPath or XSLT. I don't recognize it. That doesn't mean much; there may be zillions of people who do. But in general it's hard to tell what something means unless you know what language it's written in, and from this snippet, it's not obvious.